# Inconsistent/ competitive mediation vs. suppression? Positive indirect, negative direct and positive total effect

Tags: interpretation, terminology, mediation, suppressor

I am unsure about the adequate terminology for describing my results from a simple mediation model (one mediator), I have conducted using Hayes’ PROCESS macro for SPSS.

For the sake of simplicity, let’s say I investigate the effect of an experimental intervention (X) on individual well-being (Y) and whether this effect might be mediated by effective coping (M).

This is what I find:

1. A positive significant total effect of X on Y (c-path), so the intervention overall increases well-being.
2. A significant positive indirect effect of X on Y via M (a*b-path), such that the intervention increases effective coping, which in turn increases well-being.
3. Surprisingly, the direct effect (c’-path) is significant and negative (i.e., reverses its sign compared to the c-path), such that when controlling for coping, the intervention actually decreases well-being.

So, as the positive indirect effect of the intervention on well-being via coping is quite strong, it seems to outweigh the negative direct effect of the intervention on well-being, overall leading to a positive total effect of the intervention on well-being.

From my understanding of answers to similar questions here as well as the literature, e.g. MacKinnon et al. (2000), Rucker et al. (2011), Zhao et al. (2010) or Hayes (2018), I would call this pattern of results “inconsistent mediation” or “competitive mediation”, with direct and indirect effects having opposite signs.

What confuses me is that the term “inconsistent mediation” is also used synonymously with “suppression”, mostly illustrated by examples in which a non-significant total effect of X on Y (c) can be partitioned into a significant indirect (a*b) and direct (c') effect with opposite signs, canceling out each other. The way I understand it, this is also called “suppression” because the inclusion of M increases the effect of X on Y (|c’| > |c|). However, suppression seems to me an inappropriate term for my results, because the inclusion of M did not enhance the effect of X on Y: the c- and c’-path are both significant and of similar size, just have opposite signs.

Do I have a wrong understanding of the term ‘suppression’? Or can I still speak of inconsistent/competitive mediation to describe my results, even though they do not indicate suppression?